# pass php parameters to vue function inside bladee

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

In my  blade view.

```
@foreach($r_templates as $key => $rt)
    <button @click="someFunc({{$rt['title'}})">click me</button>
@endforeach

// In my vue script
someFunc(title) { console.log(title); }
```

the above code seems to not work and it does not have errors too.

but when I change the parameter to `'something'`, it works.

How do I pass a `PHP variable to a vue function?`

Comment: right square brackets missing someFunc({{$rt['title']}}) in function parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your passing string you need to add `' '`this quote

try this

```php
@foreach($r_templates as $key => $rt)
    <button @click="someFunc( '{{$rt['title'}}' )">click me</button>
@endforeach
```

Comment: damn. thanks man

Comment: It won't work if you have a single quote or double quote in the title. Also it might allow code injection. This code is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

You have no quotes arround the parameter/value.

Ensure proper quotes and escaping using the JSON function:

```
'someFunc({{ Js::from($rt['title']) }})'
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json

Comment: this also worked too. thanks